# How to toggle the switch element in wix

Tags: jquery, wix

I'm new to wix, my objective is to make switch element work when we click on it. it should show different text while we switch it i.e., on and off the element.

[image: switch element]

I've written in this way:

```
export function switchSample1_click(event) {
  if ($w('#switchSample1').checked) {
    $w('#text1').hide()
  } else
    $w("#text2").show()
}
```

But i could not show or hide by writing this. Can anyone help me in this query?

Comment: change `$w('#switchSample1').checked` to `$w('#switchSample1').is(":checked")` see if that works .

Comment: @Swati - It is showing error as *'is' does not exist on '#switchSample1'*

Comment: ahh... i see this is not jquery it has wix .Please show relevant html code or can you make this runnable it would be good that way .

Comment: @Swati - i didn't wrote any html code. I just added a select icon  to my page and i turned on Dev Mode, Below we're getting the respective code : ``` 
$w.onReady(function () {
 // Write your JavaScript here

 // To select an element by ID use: $w("#elementID")

 // Click "Preview" to run your code
});```

Comment: is this online somewhere ? also is there any error you are seeing in your current code inside console ? also is id which you have are right ?

Comment: @Swati - I'm using online wix. after replacing your code, there is an error showing **'is' does not exist on '#switchSample1' **.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229962/discussion-between-swati-and-sandhya).